# Is there a way hide the vs code test explorer permanently?

Tags: python, testing, visual-studio-code

I like using vs code to deploy python tests. I just do not like the sidebar open all the time since it is squeezing my editor windows quite a bit and I prefer checking the results of my tests in the output. But every time I run a test, the sidebar with the test explorer is popping up.

Is there a way to hide or disable the test explorer permanently?

Answer (score 2):

Hiding the activity bar works for me , right click on it and select `Hide the activity bar`
or you can use the fast command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and then search for "`Toggle activity bar visibility`"

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is actually quite a good fix. Now I have even more space for my editors ;)

Comment: It used to work. I have no idea why it does not anymore. Now even with the hidden activity bar it pops up every time.